Which app to access my Windows machine from Mac machine?
I need remotely access my Windows machine from Mac machine while I am somewhere else, mostly for chats and emails. What  web / desktop app / web app can I use? I tried a few apps, but most of them are not free or limited.

What exactly do you mean by "access"?

This question may be subject to closing, as it is a opinion based question. Consider to specify your requirements. It is sufficient, I believe to remove the "best" reference from the title and body of the question to focus on the free/chat/email aspect.

To be able to chat and check emails from another laptop

The simplest option is AnyDesk, which is free for personal use and can remotely access a Windows machine from a Mac, iPad, iPhone or even an Apple TV.
A more complex option is to install a VNC server on your Windows machine such as TigerVNC or TightVNC and then access it with the built-in VNC client in Mac OS by entering vnc://ipaddresshere:portnumberhere in Finder's Go → Connect to Server menu.
(You can also use a paid alternative VNC client, like the expensive Screens app)
